# boolean on the script, is saying error that says "not all code path return a value" for the function C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting an error message That "not all code paths return a value" for this code.

```
 public bool IsInteractable(Vector3Int position)
    {
        //getting the tile
        TileBase tile = InteractableGround.GetTile(position);

        //Checking the name of the tilemap
        if (tile != null)
        {

            if (tile.name == "Interactable")
            {

                return true;

            }

            return false;

        }

    }
```

I think the issue might be with the string for the file name, but i have copy and paste the name of the tile.

Comment: It's the `tile == null` path where you don't set a return value.

Comment: If your title is  null it has no return. The compiler is right.

Comment: This has nothing to do with unity

Comment: The entire code can be changed to something like: `return InteractableGround.GetTile(position)?.name == "Interactable";`

Answer (score 1):

It’s because when your if statement condition is not met your if block is skipped right? So the code inside your if statement is not executed.

You need to include a return false or similar after your if statement or in an else statement :)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there is one possibility where your code won't have a return statement.
Here, if your tile is null, you don't return anything, which is causing C# to throw this error.

Comment: The error is from the c# compiler, not Unity

Comment: Yes, my bad it's "which is causing C# to throw this error". Basically comes down to the same result, you need to put a return statement at the end of your function.

Comment: True! [Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75503232/edit) the answer would improve it's quality.